# Open recently saved images and display them python opencv

Tags: python, opencv

I am creating a program on Python and opencv that detects an object and when detecting it It takes a capture, the problem is that I need to use that photo just taken to apply other effects and I do not know how to do it, if you could help me it would be fantastic.
Here are the lines of code where I am saving the photos taken within a for cycle

```py
archive = cv2.imwrite(folder + '/' + date_time + str(y) + '.jpg', object)

image = cv2.imread(archive)
```

I wanted to observe it on the screen first using this line but it returns me an error

```py
cv2.imshow('object', image)
```

maybe it's very obvious but I don't know how to do it please help

Comment: cv2.imread("The Path to your image")  not  the return value of cv2.imwrite

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible code sample, and provide the stack trace of the error you describe. These will improve the quality of the answers you receive.

Answer (score 0):

Making sure the path to your image is correct. Are you getting the latest image based on the current datetime.The time will not the same with the one you saved. You can consider to get the latest image path from directory from the code below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse
import cv2
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFilter
import glob



ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-p", "--path", required=True, help="Path to the image")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())


list_of_files = glob.glob(args["path"]+"/*")
latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)
print (latest_file)
img = cv2.imread(latest_file)


cv2.namedWindow('image')
while(1):
    cv2.imshow('image',img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    if k == 27:
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thanks!, that way I can see the path of the latest image, still can't show the image with cv2.imshow

Comment: I wrote the code and edit the post. To cancel or close the cv2 windows you may simply hit ESC (k == 27).